How can I create a website in IIS using powershell?
I am trying to create a website in IIS using powershell from a php web page.
I have setup the php page, called the powershell script and got it to run with a simple command. When I try to run the line that creates the website it just doesn't do it. It does anything else in the file, just not the one line I actually need.
The command also works in powershell when I type it in, so I am presuming it is not a typo.
I have also tried setting permissions etc. That still changed nothing.
I am new to powershell, started using it yesterday. So any help would be appreciated.
Oh, and I did not write this code, but I pieced it together from different sources.
Here's my php file:
<?php
echo "<pre>";
echo Shell_Exec('powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command "& { . \"C:/test.ps1\"; }"');
echo "</pre>";
?>

Here's my .ps1 file:
New-Website -Name "MyNewSite" -Force -Port 80 -HostHeader "mynewsite.local" -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\mynewsite"

Get-Process

This might not fix your problem, but if you're just calling a *.ps1 script you don't need to use -Command "& { . \"C:/test.ps1\"; }" - you can just put -File "C:\test.ps1" - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-file----filepath-args

Redirect the output of the PowerShell command to a file to see if any errors or output are being generated when it's called from PHP. This can help in diagnosing the issue. echo Shell_Exec('powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command "& { . \"C:/test.ps1\"; }" > C:/powershell_output.txt')

Hi YurongDai - When I run what you typed exactly. Nothing works. It doesn't output to that file. I tried without the file existing and with the file existing. Did you mean to type it exactly as it is  by "Redirect the output of the powershell command to a file"? Sorry, but I'm really, really new to this, and probably a bit stupid as well :)

You can try to manually execute the command in PowerShell to see if there is any output from the command.
